# How can I send a string, that has multiple zeros to CMD?

Tags: c#, sendmessage

I have a function in WinForms C# app that sends a string (from a textbox) to an active `CMD` window, using a button.
Unfortunately, if the textbox contains multiple zeros `(0000x000F22000)`, it returns just one zero: **`0x0F220`**

How can I fix this?

```
private void but_run_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        uint wparam = 0 << 29 | 0;

        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < textBox1.Text.Length; i++)
        {
            //PostMessage(child, WM_KEYDOWN, (IntPtr)Keys.Enter, (IntPtr)wparam);
            PostMessage(cmdHwnd, WM_CHAR, (int)textBox1.Text[i], 0);
        }
        PostMessage(cmdHwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, (IntPtr)Keys.Enter, (IntPtr)wparam);

}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: You're mixing `int` (or `uint`) with `string`. In the wrong way. Show the actual code.

Comment: Don't cram code into a comment man. Edit your question and put it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the lParam to specify repeat key presses. Also, pay attention - `PostMessage` has `lParam` as the fourth parameter (`wParam` is before `lParam`), you're mixing it up in your code.

Next, don't use `(int)someChar`. You should use the `Encoding` classes to get byte values from chars.

Use SendMessage instead of PostMessage. PostMessage is asynchronous and can complicate a lot of stuff for you. You don't need the asynchronicity, so don't use it.

Next, why use `WM_CHAR`? I'd say `WM_SETTEXT` would be way more appropriate - you can send the whole text at once. Just be careful about using the native resources (eg. the string). To make this as easy as possible, you can make yourself an overload of the SendMessage method:

```
const uint WM_SETTEXT = 0x000C;

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, unit Msg, 
   IntPtr wParam, string lParam);
```

You can then simply call:

```
SendMessage(cmdHwnd, WM_SETTEXT, IntPtr.Zero, textBox1.Text);
```

Comment: sorry, I've found another solution, which looks somewhat like your version (that's why I've marked it); unfortunately this changes the caption of my console window.

Comment: @AndreiPopescu Oooh, I thought you wanted to input the text *to* a text box. If you want it the other way around, use the first part of my answer instead.

Comment: thanks, I've used PostMessage instead, with WM_CHAR.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do it like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr FindWindow(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

const int WM_CHAR = 0x0102;

public void sendText(string pText, string pCaption)
    {
        IntPtr wndHndl = FindWindow(IntPtr.Zero, pCaption);
        char[] tmpText = pText.ToCharArray();
        foreach (char c in tmpText)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
            PostMessage(wndHndl, WM_CHAR, (IntPtr)c, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
```

Where **pText** is the input string and **pCaption** is title of the window.